# Updating list of lists is happening for just one iteration but not in further iterations in Perceptron algorithm ML

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, machine-learning, perceptron

Below is my code of multi-class perceptron algorithm.
Here I am trying to update the weight vector given by list of lists - **weights**.

The logic is correct, it executes correctly for 1 iteration. The **weights** list of lists is initialized with all 0's. In the first iteration, the weights list is updated, but however in the further iterations, the list is not getting updated. I don't understand what am I doing it wrongly? Please help. Thanks

Code:
**

```
import numpy as np
data = open("mnist_data_training.csv",'r')
weights = [[0 for _ in range(784)] for _ in range(10)]
for _ in range(0,3):
    for row in data:
        lst_row = (row.rstrip('\n').split(','))
        list_row = lst_row[:-1]
        if (max_weight_index != (lst_row[784])):
            weights[lst_row[784]] = np.add(weights[lst_row[784]],list_row) **# Updating weight vector here**
            weights[max_weight_index] = numpy.subtract(weights[max_weight_index],list_row) **#Updating weight vector here**
```

**GitHub link - https://github.com/sudhakosuri/Multi-Class-Perceptron.git**

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You should really use context managers to handle file objects.

Comment: You're code seems to skip rows as long as the `max_weight_index == lst_row[784]`, I'd put the most likely point of failure there.

Comment: @AMC Changed the code. I hope I am clear now.

Comment: @iggy12345 Changed the logic a bit but still not working.

Comment: @Sudha, your logic is still equivalent, why are you skipping if `max_weight_index == lst_row[784]`?

Comment: @iggy12345 Because I did not want the other condition as I was doing nothing in it. Can you please elaborate on what the problem could be? Why my weight vector is updated in first iteration only but stays the same in all subsequent iterations.

Comment: If `max_weight_index` starts not equal to `lst_row[784]` on the first iteration, but then equal on all subsequent iterations, your weight list will never get updated

Comment: @iggy12345 That was my first intuition but no, it is going into the condition. I checked.

Comment: Well, without being able to run the code myself, I can't really get much farther than that, at the moment

Comment: @iggy12345 Is there a way that I can share the code and the files to you for you to check?

Comment: Put everything onto a GitHub repo and then post the link into you question body and I'll try and get to it

Comment: @iggy12345 Added the source code and the test files into the repository and the question has been updated with the link. Thank you for the help !

Comment: sorry for taking so long, but I stepped through your code, and the weights appear to be getting updated past the first iteration

Comment: Thanks for your time for working on this. I have found the issue. The issue was the file pointer. Using seek() in the beginning of the iteration has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using filepointer.seek() at the beginning of the iteration has solved the issue.